# Three.js importing object using JSON from blender

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I am using Blender plugin to export JSON files, but for some reason I cannot export the texture of my object.

the materials section of the JSON file looks like:

```
    "materials" : [ {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "new",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorEmissive" : [0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "shading" : "Lambert",
    "specularCoef" : 50,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
}],
```

and the JavaScript part is :

```
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();          

loader.load( "./try.js", function(geometry,materials) {
    material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    object.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    object.position.x=0;
    object.position.y=0;
    object.position.z=0;
});

loader.onLoadComplete=function(){ //render
}
```

I followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUkNOF8eORA to create object. (not what I would do, but in this way we have the same starting point)

Comment: There are no texture maps defined in your material. Take a look at the JSON format definition at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki

Comment: Yes I got that.  My question is why blender plug in is not exporting texture map

Comment: It seems that doing the Unwrapping (mesh - UV unwrap - Unvrap) is crucial since it creates the UV coordinates and allows the exporter to save them in the .json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered is: you map a texture on your geometry with blender, using the various mesh- UV - methods, and the .json file generated by the exporter will store the informations about the UV mapping. That UV mapping is of course related to the texture image you choose.

The JSON file supports a lot of stuff that are not supported by the loader (yet ?) like, for example, animations, camera and light proprieties, etc. One of the feature that is not supported by the loader is exactly what I was looking for. It seems that in the specification of the JSON file you can add the name of the image file for the texture. But neither the exporter nor the loader are able to do something with it.

edit: this https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5502 pull request shows that they are working on it, maybe next version of three.js will work